# Loading Random prefabs in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I make random **prefabs** with the different positions in Unity 3D?

```
private void SpawnAllEnemy() { 
    // For all the prefabs 
    for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.Length; i++) { 
        // ... create enemy, set their player number and references needed for control. 
        Enemy[i].m_Instance = Instantiate(m_EnemyPrefab, 
                                      m_Tanks[i].m_SpawnPoint.position, 
                                      Enemy[i].m_SpawnPoint.rotation) as GameObject; 
        Enemy[i].PlayerNumber = i + 1; 
        Enemy[i].Setup(); 
    } 
}
```

This is the method but I want to random the position of enemy as well as the enemy appears at random time

Comment: private void SpawnAllEnemy()
    {
        // For all the prefabs
        for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... create enemy, set their player number and references needed for control.
            Enemy[i].m_Instance =
                Instantiate(m_EnemyPrefab, m_Tanks[i].m_SpawnPoint.position, Enemy[i].m_SpawnPoint.rotation) as GameObject;
            Enemy[i].PlayerNumber = i + 1;
            Enemy[i].Setup();
        }
    }
This is the method but I want to random the position of enemy as well as the enemy appears at random time

Answer (score 0):

you can random the spawn in this code 
`GameObject SpawnLocation = (GameObject)Instantiate(EnemyObject, spawnLocation, Quaternion.identity);`

Answer (score 0):

if you want the nice random position without making the list of objects and vector 3 lists or array you can use Random.insideUnitCircle .
and if you want to change pos and rotation better assign the Instantiate object to the game object then can modify the rotation and position easier.
temp GameObjcet= Instantiate(prefabList[Random.Range[0,prefabList]
also you can make function to generate uniq int every time .

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method. same goes to the position.

```
GameObject[] prefabs;
Vector3[] enemyPosition;
Instantiate(Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length), Random.Range(0, enemyPosition.Length), Quaternion.Identity)
```

Comment: I think you meant to do something like: `Instantiate(prefabs[Random.range(0, prefabs.Length-1)]);`

Comment: what is this did you check the overload of Instantiate Method?

Comment: surely he know the right way of Instantiate Method. The thing im trying to point out is the `Random.Range()` method itself